# Get coordinates of two different places on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

**Aim of my code:**

1. Draw a small rectangle on a HTML canvas whenever a user clicks the canvas. The rectangle should have a small number representing the number of rectangles made by the user.
2. The user should be able to connect any two rectangles using a straight line. (Preferably by just pressing left mouse button, and taking the mouse from first rectangle to second rectangle)

**Approach and my attempt**

As you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jqptynt/) , I have been able to achieve the first part of above very well. On clicking on the canvas, a rectangle with a number inside of it is made. But I am really clueless about the second part.

How do I make the user connect any two made rectangles? I want the connection to be made only if a rectangle is there ( So I would need to store coordinates of every rectangle that has been made, that's okay as I can use an array for that ). 
Basically, I just want to check if the mousedown was at one place and mouseup at the other. 
How do I get these two different coordinates ( one of mousedown and other of mouseup ) , and draw a line between them? 
I have given the Fiddle above but still here's my jquery:

```
$(function () {
    var x, y;
    var globalCounter = 0;
    $('#mycanvas').on("click", function (event) {

        x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        x -= mycanvas.offsetLeft;

        y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        y -= mycanvas.offsetLeft;

        // alert("x:"+x+"y: "+y);

        drawRectangle(x, y);
    });

    function drawRectangle(x, y) {
        var acanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var context = acanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.strokeRect(x, y, 25, 25);
        globalCounter++;
        writeNo(x, y, globalCounter);
    }

    function writeNo(x, y, n) {
        var acanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var context = acanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = "bold 14px sans-serif";
        context.fillText(n, x + 8, y + 12.5);
    }
});
```

The main question is therefore: **connecting the two made rectangles by mousedrag**

How do I achieve this? 
Thank You.

Comment: how is that "connect" looking like?

Comment: The connect is just a line, straight line connecting the centers of two rectangles

Comment: You first need to use different events. one for creating an element and another one for drawing a line. you can't use click event for both activities as drawing a line will also indirectly uses click event. mouseup and mousedown will create a conflict so better to differentiate them. I have done kinda same activity at https://github.com/alpesh1988/ETSAssignment ..you can use it as reference. let me know if you have doubts.

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati unless you use collision detection to detect when you have clicked on a sqaure, then you can click another to connect (you can't overlap squares with this method)

Comment: @dwana exactly...clicking on a canvas, it is creating an element. so how will you identify the click(on square) in case of drawing a line ?

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati save the coords of the squares when drawn in a global array and then basic collision detection with the mouse position (should i make a fiddle?)

Comment: @AkshayArora you can join the discussion.

Comment: @dwana yaah, sure if it solves akshay's problem.

Comment: Well, if you see the answer below, BYossarian did exactly what dwana is saying, the coordinates of the squares have been stored in an array but @Alpesh Prajapati has a decent point, I will better make a rectangle on 'right-click' rather than a normal click so that a user who wants to connect two rectangles does not end up (accidently) making a new rectangle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/4jqptynt/4/

Ok, first I did a little refactoring for your code to make things easier. Just stuff like putting the code that gets the canvas coordinates into it's own function, and caching some variables (like the canvas context) in the outer function's scope. Oh, and defining your rectangle dimensions as constants because we'll be using the same numbers in a couple of different places.

As you said, the first thing we need is to keep track of the existing rectangles using an array `rects` (easy enough to do within `drawRectangle`). Then we need a function to check if a particular pair of coordinates are within some rectangle:

```
function inRectangle(x, y) {

    for (var i = 0, l = rects.length; i < l; i++) {

        if ((x - rects[i].x) <= RECT_X && (y - rects[i].y) <= RECT_Y && 
                (x - rects[i].x) >= 0 && (y - rects[i].y) >= 0) {

            return i;    

        }

    }

}
```

where `RECT_X` & `RECT_Y` define the sides of the rectangle. If the coordinates do exist within some rectangle then this will return the index of that rectangle within the `rects` array.

Then it's a case of checking whether or not a mousedown occurred within a rectangle, noting that `inRectangle` will only return a number if the mousedown event was within a rectangle:

```
$acanvas.on("mousedown", function (event) {

    var coords = getCoords(event),
        rect = inRectangle(coords.x, coords.y); 

    if (typeof rect === "number") {
        dragStart = rect + 1;
    } else {
        drawRectangle(coords.x, coords.y);
    }

});
```

if so, make a note of which rectangle using `dragStart`, if not draw a rectangle as before.

Then to complete the drag, we need to attach a handler to `mouseup`:

```
$acanvas.on("mouseup", function (event) {

    if (!dragStart) { return; }

    var coords = getCoords(event),
        rect = inRectangle(coords.x, coords.y);   

    if (typeof rect === "number") {
        drawConnection(dragStart - 1, rect);
    }

    dragStart = 0;

});
```

If no drag was started, then it does nothing. If it's coordinates aren't within a rectangle, then it does nothing but reset `dragStart`. If however, it is within a rectangle, then it draws a connecting line:

```
function drawConnection(rect1, rect2) {

    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(rects[rect1].x + RECT_X/2, rects[rect1].y + RECT_Y/2);
    context.lineTo(rects[rect2].x + RECT_X/2, rects[rect2].y + RECT_Y/2);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();

}
```